# Convert images in a compressed file such as a zip file to numpy array in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

We could combine module `zipfile.ZipFile` and `PIL.Image.open` to read the image from the compressed file. However, we might receive an error `io.UnsupportedOperation: seek` after we call `PIL.Image.open`. It refers to the condition that I passed a `ZipExtFile` object to `PIL.Image.open` function as below:

```
 from zipfile import ZipFile
 from PIL import Image

 zipf = ZipFile(path, "r")

 f = zipf.open("test.jpg")

 img = Image.open(f)
```

So, how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we could solve this problem by reading the content of the image and then convert it to `cStringIO` buffer. The code is below:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image

zipf = ZipFile(path, "r")

# read instead of open
content = zipf.read("test.jpg")

img = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(content))
```

Comment: You should use the more modern [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). That way your code will work on Python 3 and Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.7 `ZipExtFile` objects now support seek operations. If you upgrade to python 3.7.2 or newer, then your code should work.