# ZipExtFile does not have a seek method in python3.7.0

Tags: python, zip, python-3.7

The [zipfile documentation for python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open) states that the `zipfile.ZipFile.open` method returns a `ZipExtFile` object with a `seek` method:

> With mode 'r' the file-like object (`ZipExtFile`) is read-only and provides the following methods: `read()`, `readline()`, `readlines()`, `seek()`, `tell()`, `__iter__()`, `__next__()`. These objects can operate independently of the `ZipFile`.

However, when I try to run my test code:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

text = b'hello world'

with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as inzip:
    with inzip.open('eggs.txt', 'w') as infile:
        infile.write(text)

with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'r') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
        myfile.seek(0)
        print(myfile.read())
```

Then I get this error message:

```
$ python3.7 zip_test.py
b'hello world'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zip_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    myfile.seek(0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1025, in seek
    self._fileobj.seek(self._orig_compress_start)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 704, in seek
    if self.writing():
AttributeError: '_SharedFile' object has no attribute 'writing'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

**Other reading**

Here are some SO questions where people seem to be running into this issue, albeit perhaps with older python interpreters:

- [Error when loading audio file from zip in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311026/error-when-loading-audio-file-from-zip-in-python)
- [Convert images in a compressed file such as a zip file to numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270071/convert-images-in-a-compressed-file-such-as-a-zip-file-to-numpy-array-in-python)

**Update**

I am running python version `3.7.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer Python 3.7.x release, you ran into [confirmed and fixed bugs in the `ZipFile.seek()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8527), see [issue #34035](https://bugs.python.org/issue34035).

Those fixes were landed in the [3.7.1rc1 release](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#id24), but I'd recommend going straight to 3.7.2 if possible.

Comment: Thanks! This is slightly off-topic, but do you know if the seek operation is O(1) for compressed files?

Comment: @winni2k: the `.seek(0)` call is, because the `ZipExtFile()` object records where the compressed data stream starts at so can do a O(1) `.seek()` call on the underlying zipped file object. For other offsets, it is not O(1), no. See the [`.seek()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4e6646fef5d2cc53422e4eca0b18201ed5a5c4b6/Lib/zipfile.py#L1018-L1062) for details, but it has to make a read call if the new position is not within the current buffered block in `self._readbuffer`.